# How to do a groupby on an empty set of columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

I am hitting on a corner case in pandas. I am trying to use the agg fn but without doing a groupby. Say I want an aggregation on the entire `dataframe`, i.e.

```
from pandas import *
DF = DataFrame( randn(5,3), index = list( "ABCDE"), columns = list("abc") )
DF.groupby([]).agg({'a' : np.sum, 'b' : np.mean } ) # <--- does not work
```

And `DF.agg( {'a' ... } )` does not work either.

My workaround is to do `DF['Total'] = 'Total'` then do a `DF.groupby(['Total'])` but this seems a bit artificial.

Has anyone got a cleaner solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so great either, but for this case, if you pass a function returning True at least it wouldn't require changing `df`:

```
>>> from pandas import *
>>> df = DataFrame( np.random.randn(5,3), index = list( "ABCDE"), columns = list("abc") )
>>> df.groupby(lambda x: True).agg({'a' : np.sum, 'b' : np.mean } )
             a         b
True  1.836649 -0.692655
>>> 
>>> df['total'] = 'total'
>>> df.groupby(['total']).agg({'a' : np.sum, 'b' : np.mean } ) 
              a         b
total                    
total  1.836649 -0.692655
```

You could use various builtins instead of `lambda x: True` but they're less explicit and only work accidentally.

Answer (score 2):

Having an analogous `DataFrame.aggregate` method is a good idea. Creating an issue here:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1623

Comment: Cool @Wes MCKinney - perhaps you could also make DF.groupby([]) return DF? Thx

Comment: I also noticed that for some functions, like `np.std` this gives an error: `IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed.`. It seems to choke on the extra structure of a pandas Series. If you use `lambda x: np.std(x.values)` as the passed-in function, this fixes it. But it seems like this should be Pandas responsibility. Maybe a try-catch sort of thing where if doesn't work as-is then also try applying it on column.values before giving up? There may be good reasons for avoiding this; just a suggestion.

Comment: @EMS can you report an issue that reproduces what you're seeing?