# Creating a partial SAS PROC SUMMARY replacement in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

We are working to get off of SAS and onto Python/Pandas.  However, one thing we are having trouble with is creating a replacement for `PROC SUMMARY` (AKA `PROC MEANS`) that has the SAS routine's flexibility. For non-SAS users: `PROC SUMMARY` is just a routine that produces a table containing "descriptive statistics for variables across all observations or within groups of observations" in a dataset, to paraphrase the SAS documentation. Our requirements are just a small subset of the full functionality - outputting a table where we have:

- Ability to apply different stats to different columns (for now just count, sum, mean, weighted mean)
- Ability to handle zero to many grouping variables
- Ability to specify a weight variable for weighted mean

We are not trying to do anything else (anything graphical, etc.)

Here is what we have so far:

```
def wmean_ungrouped (d,w):
    return (d.dot(w)).sum() / w.sum()

def wmean_grouped (group, var_name_in, var_name_weight):
    d = group[var_name_in]
    w = group[var_name_weight]
    return (d * w).sum() / w.sum()

FUNCS = {
    "mean"   : np.mean ,
    "sum"   : np.sum ,
    "count" : np.count_nonzero
}

def my_summary (
        data ,
        var_names_in ,
        var_names_out ,
        var_functions ,
        var_name_weight = None ,
        var_names_group = None
):
    result = DataFrame()

    if var_names_group is not None:
        grouped = data.groupby (var_names_group)
        for var_name_in, var_name_out, var_function in \
                zip(var_names_in,var_names_out,var_functions):
            if var_function == "wmean":
                func = lambda x : wmean_grouped (x, var_name_in, var_name_weight)
                result[var_name_out] = Series(grouped.apply(func))
            else:
                func = FUNCS[var_function]
                result[var_name_out] = grouped[var_name_in].apply(func)
    else:
        for var_name_in, var_name_out, var_function in \
                zip(var_names_in,var_names_out,var_functions):
            if var_function == "wmean":
                result[var_name_out] = \
                    Series(wmean_ungrouped(data[var_name_in], data[var_name_weight]))
            else:
                func = FUNCS[var_function]
                result[var_name_out] = Series(func(data[var_name_in]))

    return result
```

Here is a sample call to the `my_summary()` function:

```
    my_summary (
        data=df,
        var_names_in=["x_1","x_1","x_1","x_1"] ,
        var_names_out=[
            "x_1_c","x_1_s","x_1_m","x_1_wm"
        ] ,
        var_functions=["count","sum","mean","wmean"] ,
        var_name_weight="val_1" ,
        var_names_group=["Region","Category"]
)
```

`my_summary()` works, but as you can see, its implementation is not the prettiest. Here are the main issues:

- **Two different code paths depending on grouped or ungrouped** - this stems completely from the fact that `DataFrame` and `DataFrameGroupBy` have different ways for applying a programmatically-selected reducing function to a single column. For `DataFrame`, the only way I've found is directly invoking `func(data[var_name_in])`. `data[var_name_in].apply(func)` doesn't work because `apply()` on a `Series` does not reduce (unlike `apply()` on a `DataFrame`). On the other hand, for `DataFrameGroupBy`, I have to use that very approach: `grouped[var_name_in].apply(func)`. That's because something like `func(grouped[var_name_in])` will not work (no reason it should.)
- **Special treatment for weighted mean** - this is because it operates on two columns, unlike all the other calculations, which operate on just one; I don't know if this can be helped.
- **Two different weighted mean functions** - this is a consequence of the first issue. The ungrouped function has `Series`-type parameters and needs `dot()` to multiply and reduce them; the grouped function eventually deals with `SeriesGroupBy` objects and has to use the `*` operator (acknowledgements to [the answer to this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951341/pandas-dataframe-aggregate-function-using-multiple-columns) for the weighted average function code.)

So my questions are:

- Is there something native to pandas that can do all of this (i.e. throw out the above and use that instead)?
- If not, are there any fixes to any of the issues mentioned above?
- By any chance, is there some way to group by nothing - that is, to obtain a `DataFrameGroupBy` object from a `DataFrame` without grouping on any variable? Then the code paths would be reduced as we would be dealing with the `DataFrameGroupBy` interface exclusively.

### Update (old - scroll down for current)

@JohnE's answer provides a way to group by nothing:  `groupby(lambda x: True)`. This is a workaround that he spotted [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492215/how-to-do-a-groupby-on-an-empty-set-of-columns-in-pandas) (which, incidentally, features an answer from Wes himself speaking of the need for a `DataFrame.agg()`, which would serve the same purpose). @JohnE's excellent solution allows us to deal exclusively with objects of type `DataFrameGroupBy`, and instantly reduces most of the code paths. I was able to reduce further using some functional gimmickry that is now possible because we have only `DataFrameGroupBy` instances. Basically, all functions are generated as needed - the "generators" (in quotes here so as to not be confused with Python generator expressions)  take two parameters: value column name and weight column name, the second of which is ignored in all cases except `wmean`.  The generated functions are always applied over the entire `DataFrameGroupBy`, as was originally the case just with `wmean`, with the parameters being the correct column name(s) to use. I also replaced all the `np.*` implementations with pandas calculations, to better deal with `NaN` values.

Unless there is something native to pandas that can do this, this is our solution:

```
FUNC_GENS = {
    "mean"  : lambda y,z : lambda x : x[y].mean(),
    "sum"   : lambda y,z : lambda x : x[y].sum() ,
    "count" : lambda y,z : lambda x : x[y].count() ,
    "wmean" : lambda y,z : lambda x : (x[y] * x[z]).sum() / x[z].sum()
}

def my_summary (
        data ,
        var_names_in ,
        var_names_out ,
        var_functions ,
        var_name_weight = None ,
        var_names_group = None ):

    result = pd.DataFrame()

    if var_names_group is None:
        grouped = data.groupby (lambda x: True)
    else:
        grouped = data.groupby (var_names_group)

    for var_name_in, var_name_out, var_function in \
            zip(var_names_in,var_names_out,var_functions):
        func_gen = FUNC_GENS[var_function]
        func = func_gen (var_name_in, var_name_weight)
        result[var_name_out] = grouped.apply(func)

    return result
```

### Update 2019 / Current Solution

Versions of pandas released subsequent to my original post now implement most of this functionality:

- **Grouping by nothing** - Wes M. had spoken in the past of the need for a [`DataFrame.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) and [it was indeed added in version 0.20.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/whatsnew.html#agg-api-for-dataframe-series) along with a [`Series.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html).
- **Multiple aggregations of multiple columns, with specified names for output columns** - this is [now part of pandas as of version 0.25.+](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling) in the form of [`NamedAgg` inputs to the `agg()` function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation)

So, basically everything except the weighted average. A good current solution for that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521027/groupby-weighted-average-and-sum-in-pandas-dataframe#31521177).

Comment: Just as an aside `df.describe()` will give you a summary of stats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here's a quickie that does get at two issues (but still requires a different function for weighted mean).  Mostly it uses the trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11492215/how-to-do-a-groupby-on-an-empty-set-of-columns-in-pandas) (credit to @DSM) to get around your empty group by doing `groupby(lamda x: True)`.  It would be great if there was a kwarg for 'weights' on stuff like means but there is not, to my knowledge.  Apparently there is a package for weighted quantiles mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102867/python-weighted-median-algorithm-with-pandas) based on numpy but I don't know anything about it.  Great project btw!

(note that names are mostly the same as yours, I just added a '2' to wmean_grouped and my_summary, otherwise you can use the same calling interface)

```
def wmean_grouped2 (group, var_name_in, var_name_weight):
    d = group[var_name_in]
    w = group[var_name_weight]
    return (d * w).sum() / w.sum()

FUNCS = { "mean"  : np.mean ,
          "sum"   : np.sum ,
          "count" : np.count_nonzero }

def my_summary2 (
        data ,
        var_names_in ,
        var_names_out ,
        var_functions ,
        var_name_weight = None ,
        var_names_group = None ):

    result = pd.DataFrame()

    if var_names_group is None:
        grouped = data.groupby (lambda x: True)
    else:
        grouped = data.groupby (var_names_group)

    for var_name_in, var_name_out, var_function in \
            zip(var_names_in,var_names_out,var_functions):
        if var_function == "wmean":
            func = lambda x : wmean_grouped2 (x, var_name_in, var_name_weight)
            result[var_name_out] = pd.Series(grouped.apply(func))
        else:
            func = FUNCS[var_function]
            result[var_name_out] = grouped[var_name_in].apply(func)

    return result
```

Comment: This is terrific. The `groupby(lambda x: True)` hack is just the trick, opening a whole realm of possibilities. I also appreciated your link to the `groupby(None)` question, which included an answer  from Wes himself where he added the implementation of a very similar `DataFram.agg()` as an open issue to Pandas (unfortunately still open.)

Comment: Cool, glad that helps.  You'd think there might be something more elegant than that, but at least it does seem to work well.

Comment: Agreed. Hopefully more stuff like this will be implemented as momentum builds behind the platform. These are the kinds of things to convince people to move off older platforms like SAS.