# groupby weighted average and sum in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
    Out[78]: 
   contract month year  buys  adjusted_lots    price
0         W     Z    5  Sell             -5   554.85
1         C     Z    5  Sell             -3   424.50
2         C     Z    5  Sell             -2   424.00
3         C     Z    5  Sell             -2   423.75
4         C     Z    5  Sell             -3   423.50
5         C     Z    5  Sell             -2   425.50
6         C     Z    5  Sell             -3   425.25
7         C     Z    5  Sell             -2   426.00
8         C     Z    5  Sell             -2   426.75
9        CC     U    5   Buy              5  3328.00
10       SB     V    5   Buy              5    11.65
11       SB     V    5   Buy              5    11.64
12       SB     V    5   Buy              2    11.60
```

I need a sum of adjusted_lots   , price which is weighted average , of price and adjusted_lots , grouped by all the other columns , ie. grouped by (contract, month , year and buys)

Similar solution on R was achieved by following code, using dplyr, however unable to do the same in pandas.

```
> newdf = df %>%
  select ( contract , month , year , buys , adjusted_lots , price ) %>%
  group_by( contract , month , year ,  buys) %>%
  summarise(qty = sum( adjusted_lots) , avgpx = weighted.mean(x = price , w = adjusted_lots) , comdty = "Comdty" )

> newdf
Source: local data frame [4 x 6]

  contract month year comdty qty     avgpx
1        C     Z    5 Comdty -19  424.8289
2       CC     U    5 Comdty   5 3328.0000
3       SB     V    5 Comdty  12   11.6375
4        W     Z    5 Comdty  -5  554.8500
```

is the same possible by groupby or any other solution ?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

**EDIT:** update aggregation so it works with recent version of pandas

To pass multiple functions to a groupby object, you need to pass a tuples with the aggregation functions and the column to which the function applies:

```
# Define a lambda function to compute the weighted mean:
wm = lambda x: np.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, "adjusted_lots"])

# Define a dictionary with the functions to apply for a given column:
# the following is deprecated since pandas 0.20:
# f = {'adjusted_lots': ['sum'], 'price': {'weighted_mean' : wm} }
# df.groupby(["contract", "month", "year", "buys"]).agg(f)

# Groupby and aggregate with namedAgg [1]:
df.groupby(["contract", "month", "year", "buys"]).agg(adjusted_lots=("adjusted_lots", "sum"),  
                                                      price_weighted_mean=("price", wm))

                          adjusted_lots  price_weighted_mean
contract month year buys                                    
C        Z     5    Sell            -19           424.828947
CC       U     5    Buy               5          3328.000000
SB       V     5    Buy              12            11.637500
W        Z     5    Sell             -5           554.850000
```

You can see more here:

- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once

and in a similar question here:

- [Apply multiple functions to multiple groupby columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14529838/apply-multiple-functions-to-multiple-groupby-columns)

[1] : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#groupby-aggregation-with-relabeling

Comment: I tried this and I got what I wanted except, that first few columns became multi indices. Could you please let us know how we can fix that ? I want it to be a data frame with all the index as columns. as in your example ```(contract,month,year.buys)``` became indices.

Comment: have you tried `df.reset_index()` ? Otherwise I suggest you open a new question with what you have, what you tried and what you'd like.

Comment: can i clarify what does x.index represent from wm = lambda x: np.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, "adjusted_lots"]) ? @jrjc

Comment: Great solution! It saved me here. Is there a way to do it in a expanding().mean() rationale?

Comment: Hey guys, I would like to recommend the answers below since they are not only easy to remember but also vectorized, so much faster.

Comment: This is great thanks! Is there a way to prevent ZeroDivisionError besides filtering out adjusted_lots  =0 ?

Answer (score 17):

Doing weighted average by groupby(...).apply(...) can be very slow (100x from the following).
See my answer (and others) on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44683506/6421575).

```
def weighted_average(df,data_col,weight_col,by_col):
    df['_data_times_weight'] = df[data_col]*df[weight_col]
    df['_weight_where_notnull'] = df[weight_col]*pd.notnull(df[data_col])
    g = df.groupby(by_col)
    result = g['_data_times_weight'].sum() / g['_weight_where_notnull'].sum()
    del df['_data_times_weight'], df['_weight_where_notnull']
    return result
```

Comment: your solution doesn't include 'adjusted_lot sums' from the original problem that needs to be there.

Comment: in case someone also needs help understanding this, weighted average is normally: val_0 * weight_0 + val_1 * weight_1 + ... + val_n * weight_n, where all the weights sum up to 1.0. When sum(weight) != 0,  you need to normalize it but dividing it by the total weight. In this method, we calculate the val_i * non-normalized_weight_i (_data_times_weight) and the separate non_normalized_weight_i (when data is not null, _weight_where_notnull). We then group and then sum each group's val_i*non_normalized_weight_i and divide by the total non-normalized_weight of the group in order to normalize it

Answer (score 14):

Wouldn't it be a lot more simpler to do this.

1. Multiply (adjusted_lots * price_weighted_mean) into a new column "X"
2. Use groupby().sum() for columns "X" and "adjusted_lots" to get
   grouped df df_grouped
3. Compute weighted average on the df_grouped as
   df_grouped['X']/df_grouped['adjusted_lots']

Comment: This way is just simply easier to remember. Don't need to look up the syntax everytime.

Comment: And also this way is much faster. The highest upvoted answer is very slow when dealing with billion-level data.

Comment: Should "price_weighted_mean" in step 1 actually be "price"?

Answer (score 8):

The solution that uses a dict of aggregation functions will be deprecated in a future version of pandas (version 0.22):

```
FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future 
version return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
```

Use a groupby apply and return a Series to rename columns as discussed in:
[Rename result columns from Pandas aggregation ("FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635626/rename-result-columns-from-pandas-aggregation-futurewarning-using-a-dict-with)

```
def my_agg(x):
    names = {'weighted_ave_price': (x['adjusted_lots'] * x['price']).sum()/x['adjusted_lots'].sum()}
    return pd.Series(names, index=['weighted_ave_price'])
```

produces the same result:

```
>df.groupby(["contract", "month", "year", "buys"]).apply(my_agg)

                          weighted_ave_price
contract month year buys                    
C        Z     5    Sell          424.828947
CC       U     5    Buy          3328.000000
SB       V     5    Buy            11.637500
W        Z     5    Sell          554.850000
```

Comment: I have zero values in my dataframe for the weighted column. In this case it would be the adjusted_lots. I want to avoid this warning: **RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars.** What's an efficient way to do that using this setup? A possible method would be: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49864679/pandas-numpy-weighted-average-zerodivisionerror), but I do not know how to combine this with your solution. Insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The way, you phrase your answer, might be misread. What will be deprecated is the ability to aggregate and rename and add a mulitlevel index at the same time. You can still use the dictionary to use different and multiple aggregation functions per column in future.

Comment: @InderJalli Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69787938/) will help with handling zeros.

Answer (score 3):

With [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar), you don't have to learn pandas APIs to transition your R code:

```py
>>> from datar.all import f, tibble, c, rep, select, summarise, sum, weighted_mean, group_by
>>> df = tibble(
...     contract=c('W', rep('C', 8), 'CC', rep('SB', 3)),
...     month=c(rep('Z', 9), 'U', rep('V', 3)),
...     year=5,
...     buys=c(rep('Sell', 9), rep('Buy', 4)),
...     adjusted_lots=[-5, -3, -2, -2, -3, -2, -3, -2, -2, 5, 5, 5, 2],
...     price=[554.85, 424.50, 424.00, 423.75, 423.50, 425.50, 425.25, 426.00, 426.75,3328.00, 11.65, 11.64, 1
1.60]
... )
>>> df
   contract month  year  buys  adjusted_lots    price
0         W     Z     5  Sell             -5   554.85
1         C     Z     5  Sell             -3   424.50
2         C     Z     5  Sell             -2   424.00
3         C     Z     5  Sell             -2   423.75
4         C     Z     5  Sell             -3   423.50
5         C     Z     5  Sell             -2   425.50
6         C     Z     5  Sell             -3   425.25
7         C     Z     5  Sell             -2   426.00
8         C     Z     5  Sell             -2   426.75
9        CC     U     5   Buy              5  3328.00
10       SB     V     5   Buy              5    11.65
11       SB     V     5   Buy              5    11.64
12       SB     V     5   Buy              2    11.60
>>> newdf = df >> \
...   select(f.contract, f.month, f.year, f.buys, f.adjusted_lots, f.price) >> \
...   group_by(f.contract, f.month, f.year, f.buys) >> \
...   summarise(
...       qty = sum(f.adjusted_lots), 
...       avgpx = weighted_mean(x = f.price , w = f.adjusted_lots), 
...       comdty = "Comdty"
...   )
[2021-05-24 13:11:03][datar][   INFO] `summarise()` has grouped output by ['contract', 'month', 'year'] (overr
ide with `_groups` argument)
>>> 
>>> newdf
  contract month  year  buys  qty        avgpx  comdty
0        C     Z     5  Sell  -19   424.828947  Comdty
1       CC     U     5   Buy    5  3328.000000  Comdty
2       SB     V     5   Buy   12    11.637500  Comdty
3        W     Z     5  Sell   -5   554.850000  Comdty
[Groups: ['contract', 'month', 'year'] (n=4)]
```

I am the author of the package. Feel free to submit issues if you have any questions.

Comment: how is pandas not adding a weighted mean function...

Answer (score 1):

This combines the [original approach by jrjc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31521177/) with the [closure approach by MB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69533593/). It has the advantage of being able to reuse the closure function.

```py
import pandas as pd

def group_weighted_mean_factory(df: pd.DataFrame, weight_col_name: str):
    # Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69787938/
    def group_weighted_mean(x):
        try:
            return np.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, weight_col_name])
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            return np.average(x)
    return group_weighted_mean

df = ...  # Define
group_weighted_mean = group_weighted_mean_factory(df, "adjusted_lots")
g = df.groupby(...)  # Define
agg_df = g.agg({'price': group_weighted_mean})
```

This approach however is needlessly more complex than the [answer by Rohit P](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62810403/). In retrospect, I would just use the answer by Rohit P.

Answer (score 0):

ErnestScribbler's answer is much faster than the accepted solution. Here a multivariate analogue:

```
def weighted_average(df,data_col,weight_col,by_col):
    ''' Now data_col can be a list of variables '''
    df_data = df[data_col].multiply(df[weight_col], axis='index')
    df_weight = pd.notnull(df[data_col]).multiply(df[weight_col], axis='index')
    df_data[by_col] = df[by_col]
    df_weight[by_col] = df[by_col]    
    result = df_data.groupby(by_col).sum() / df_weight.groupby(by_col).sum()
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this thread when confronted with a similar problem. In my case, I wanted to generate a weighted metric of a quarterback rating should more than one quarterback have attempted a pass in a given NFL game.

I may change the code if I start running into significant performance issues as I scale. For now, I preferred squeezing my solution into the `.agg` function alongside other transforms. Happy to see if someone has a simpler solution to achieve the same end. Ultimately, I employed a closure pattern.

The magic of the closure approach, if this is an unfamiliar pattern to a future reader, is that I can still return a simple function to pandas' `.agg()` method, but I get to do so with some additional information preconfigured from the top-level `factory` function.

```py
def weighted_mean_factory(*args, **kwargs):
    weights = kwargs.get('w').copy()
    
    def weighted_mean(x):
        x_mask = ~np.isnan(x)
        w = weights.loc[x.index]
        
        if all(v is False for v in x_mask):
            raise ValueError('there are no non-missing x variable values')

        return np.average(x[x_mask], weights=w[x_mask])
    
    return weighted_mean

res_df = df.groupby(['game_id', 'team'])\
    .agg(pass_player_cnt=('attempts', count_is_not_zero),
         completions=('completions', 'sum'), 
         attempts=('attempts', 'sum'),
         pass_yds=('pass_yards', 'sum'),
         pass_tds=('pass_tds', 'sum'), 
         pass_int=('pass_int', 'sum'), 
         sack_taken=('sacks_taken', 'sum'), 
         sack_yds_loss=('sack_yds_loss', 'sum'), 
         longest_completion=('longest_completion', 'max'),
         qbr_w_avg=('qb_rating', weighted_mean_factory(x='qb_rating', w=df['attempts']))
         )
```

Some basic benchmarking stats on a DataFrame with the shape (5436, 31) are below and are not cause for concern on my end in terms of performance at this stage:

```
149 ms ± 4.75 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```