# Groupby and weighted average

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame.from_items([('STAND_ID',[1,1,2,3,3,3]),('Species',['Conifer','Broadleaves','Conifer','Broadleaves','Conifer','Conifer']),
                             ('Height',[20,19,13,24,25,18]),('Stems',[1500,2000,1000,1200,1700,1000]),('Volume',[200,100,300,50,100,10])])

   STAND_ID      Species  Height  Stems  Volume
0         1      Conifer      20   1500     200
1         1  Broadleaves      19   2000     100
2         2      Conifer      13   1000     300
3         3  Broadleaves      24   1200      50
4         3      Conifer      25   1700     100
5         3      Conifer      18   1000      10
```

I want to group by STAND_ID and Species, apply a weighted mean on Height and Stems with Volume as weight and unstack.

So i try:

```
newdf=df.groupby(['STAND_ID','Species']).agg({'Height':lambda x: np.average(x['Height'],weights=x['Volume']),
                                              'Stems':lambda x: np.average(x['Stems'],weights=x['Volume'])}).unstack()
```

Which give me error:

> builtins.KeyError: 'Height'

How can i fix this?

Comment: Also seems to be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521027/groupby-weighted-average-and-sum-in-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your error is because you can not do multiple series/column operations using `agg`.  Agg takes one series/column as a time.  Let's use `apply` and `pd.concat`.

```
g = df.groupby(['STAND_ID','Species'])
newdf = pd.concat([g.apply(lambda x: np.average(x['Height'],weights=x['Volume'])), 
                   g.apply(lambda x: np.average(x['Stems'],weights=x['Volume']))], 
                   axis=1, keys=['Height','Stems']).unstack()
```

#### Edit a better solution:

```
g = df.groupby(['STAND_ID','Species'])
newdf = g.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([np.average(x['Height'], weights=x['Volume']), 
                             np.average(x['Stems'],weights=x['Volume'])], 
                                    index=['Height','Stems'])).unstack()
```

Output:

```
              Height                  Stems             
Species  Broadleaves    Conifer Broadleaves      Conifer
STAND_ID                                                
1               19.0  20.000000      2000.0  1500.000000
2                NaN  13.000000         NaN  1000.000000
3               24.0  24.363636      1200.0  1636.363636
```

Comment: why do you say that the second solution is better please ?

Comment: @DL Honestly, I did this answer just 4 years ago, I am no longer convinced the second is any better.  I would need to run timings and consider other methods/recipes I know now.

Comment: I created two dataframes with `groupby()` and then implemented `pd.join()`, which i presume is most similar to the `concat()` method that you initially asseted. Performance (approximate): It computes 10k rows in 0.1 seconds.