# Pandas/numpy weighted average ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, divide-by-zero, weighted-average

Creating a lambda function to calculate weighted average and sending that to a dictionary.

```
wm = lambda x: np.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, 'WEIGHTS'])

# Define a dictionary with the functions to apply for a given column:
f = {'DRESS_AMT': 'max', 
     'FACE_AMT': 'sum',
     'Other_AMT': {'weighted_mean' : wm}}

# Groupby and aggregate with dictionary:
df2=df.groupby(['ID','COL1'], as_index=False).agg(f)
```

This code works but the weighted average lambda function fails if the weights add up to 0 `ZeroDivisionError`. In these case(s) I want the output 'Other_AMT' to just be 0.

I read a document on using np.ma.average (masked average) but could not understand how to implement it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shouldn't this be enough?

```
def wm(x):
    try: 
        return np.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, 'WEIGHTS'])
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

f = {'DRESS_AMT': 'max', 
     'FACE_AMT': 'sum',
     'Other_AMT': {'weighted_mean' : wm} }

df2=df.groupby(['ID','COL1'], as_index=False).agg(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `np.ma.average(x, weights=df.loc[x.index, 'WEIGHTS'])`