# weighted average aggregation on multiple columns of df

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, weighted-average

I'm trying to calculate a weighted average for multiple columns in a dataframe.
This is a sample of my data

| Group | Year | Month | Weight(kg) | Nitrogen | Calcium |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020 | 01 | 10000 | 10 | 70 |
| A | 2020 | 01 | 15000 | 4 | 78 |
| A | 2021 | 05 | 12000 | 5 | 66 |
| A | 2021 | 05 | 10000 | 8 | 54 |
| B | 2021 | 08 | 14000 | 10 | 90 |
| C | 2021 | 08 | 50000 | 20 | 92 |
| C | 2021 | 08 | 40000 | 10 | 95 |

My desired result would look something like this:
[image]

What I've tried:
I can get the correct weighted average values for a single column using this function:
(similar to: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521027/groupby-weighted-average-and-sum-in-pandas-dataframe))

```
def wavg(df, value, weight):
    d = df[value]
    w = df[weight]
    try:
        return (d * w).sum() / w.sum()
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return d.mean()
```

I can apply this function to a single column of my df:

```
df2 = df.groupby(["Group", "year", "month"]).apply(wavg, "Calcium", "Weight(kg").to_frame()
```

(Don't mind the different values, they are correct for the data in my notebook)

[image]

The obvious problem is that this function only works for a single column whilst I have a douzens of columns. I therefore tried a for loop:

```
column_list=[]
for column in df.columns:
  column_list.append(df.groupby(["Group", "year", "month"]).apply(wavg, column, "Weight(kg").to_frame())
```

It calculates the values correctly, but the columns are placed on top of each other instead of next to eachother. They also miss a usefull column name:

[image]

How could I adapt my code to return the desired df?

Comment: try concatinating them(on either axis according to your need): `df=pd.concat(column_list)` or `df=pd.concat(column_list,axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks, the pd.concat (column_list, axis=1) actually works. I do get a multiindex that needs some flattening but this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change function for working by multiple columns and for avoid removing column for grouping are converting to `MultiIndex`:

```
def wavg(x, value, weight):
    d = x[value]
    w = x[weight]
    try:
        return (d.mul(w, axis=0)).div(w.sum())
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return d.mean()

#columns used for groupby
groups = ["Group", "Year", "Month"]
#processing all another columns
cols = df.columns.difference(groups + ["Weight(kg)"], sort=False)

#create index and processing all columns by variable cols
df1 = (df.set_index(groups)
         .groupby(level=groups)
         .apply(wavg, cols, "Weight(kg)")
         .reset_index())
print (df2)
  Group  Year  Month    Calcium   Nitrogen
0     A  2020      1  28.000000   4.000000
1     A  2020      1  46.800000   2.400000
2     A  2021      5  36.000000   2.727273
3     A  2021      5  24.545455   3.636364
4     B  2021      8  90.000000  10.000000
5     C  2021      8  51.111111  11.111111
6     C  2021      8  42.222222   4.444444
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The code almost work but during the creation of df2 I get the following error: 
ValueError: cannot join with no overlapping index names. How could I work around this?

Comment: @brenda89 - If remove `.reset_index()` it working?

Comment: @brenda89 - What is variable `cols` ? How working all columns not used for groupby like `cols = df.columns.difference(["Group", "Year", "Month"], sort=False)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try via `concat()` and `reset_index()`:

```
df=pd.concat(column_list,axis=1).reset_index()
```

OR

you can make changes here:

```
column_list=[]
for column in df.columns:
  column_list.append(df.groupby(["Group", "year", "month"]).apply(wavg, column, "Weight(kg").reset_index())

#Finally:

df=pd.concat(column_list,axis=1)
```

Comment: Possible solution, but in term of performance is better working with all columns only once, not each column separately and then use `concat`.

Comment: @jezrael got it sir ***:)***