# Pandas Groupby Weighted Standard Deviation

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, standard-deviation, weighted

I have a dataframe:

```
             Type Weights Value  ....
    0         W     0.5    15  
    1         C     1.2    19  
    2         W     12     25  
    3         C     7.1    15    .....
    .......
    .......
```

I want to group on type and then calculate **weighted mean** and **weighted standard deviation**.

There seem to be solution available for weighted mean ([groupby weighted average and sum in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521027/groupby-weighted-average-and-sum-in-pandas-dataframe)) but **none for weighted standard deviation**.

Is there a simple way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the weighted standard deviation formula from the following link:
https://doc-archives.microstrategy.com/producthelp/10.7/FunctionsRef/Content/FuncRef/WeightedStDev__weighted_standard_deviation_of_a_sa.htm

However you can modify for a different formula

```
import numpy as np
def weighted_sd(input_df):
    weights = input_df['Weights']
    vals = input_df['Value']
    numer = np.sum(weights * (vals - vals.mean())**2)
    denom = ((vals.count()-1)/vals.count())*np.sum(weights)
    return np.sqrt(numer/denom)

print(df.groupby('Type').apply(weighted_sd))
```

Answer (score 0):

Minor correction to the weighted standard deviation formula from the previous answer.

```
import numpy as np
def weighted_sd(input_df):
    weights = input_df['Weights']
    vals = input_df['Value']

    weighted_avg = np.average(vals, weights=weights)
    
    numer = np.sum(weights * (vals - weighted_avg)**2)
    denom = ((vals.count()-1)/vals.count())*np.sum(weights)
    
    return np.sqrt(numer/denom)

print(df.groupby('Type').apply(weighted_sd))
```