# Monthly Weighted average (in Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a new column with Monthly weighted average.
I tried a few options but the weighted average calculation is taking total of column `Amount`. for example in March 2021 because there is just one value, WA should be 10*(110/100), most code calculate 10*(110/total Amount column)

Any idea how to do this?

My Data:

| Date | Column 1 | Amount | (Expected Output) Monthly WA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-Jan-2021 | 20 | 100 | 16.78 |
| 01-Jan-2021 | 25 | 110 | 16.78 |
| 01-Jan-2021 | 15 | 120 | 16.78 |
| 01-Jan-2021 | 30 | 135 | 16.78 |
| 02-Jan-2021 | 10 | 150 | 16.78 |
| 02-Jan-2021 | 12 | 160 | 16.78 |
| 02-Jan-2021 | 11 | 175 | 16.78 |
| 01-Feb-2021 | 13 | 225 | 20.09 |
| 01-Feb-2021 | 15 | 220 | 20.09 |
| 01-Feb-2021 | 17 | 158 | 20.09 |
| 02-Feb-2021 | 20 | 185 | 20.09 |
| 02-Feb-2021 | 25 | 170 | 20.09 |
| 02-Feb-2021 | 35 | 160 | 20.09 |
| 01-Mar-2021 | 10 | 110 | 10 |

Here's the code I've tried:

```py
def weight_avg(df, value, weights):
    x = df[value]  
    y = df[weights]  
    return (x*y).sum()/y.sum() <br />

df.groupby(df['Date']).apply(weight_avg, 'Column 1', 'Amount')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [groupby weighted average and sum in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521027/groupby-weighted-average-and-sum-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Your dataset has "01-Jan-2021" and "02-Jan-2021" and hence the groupby is happening on them individual. You need to extract the month and apply a group on it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I figure it out to get the correct WA values. I created a Month_Year column df['month_year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.to_period('M') and then applied the groub by with df.groupby(df['month_year']).apply(weight_avg, 'Column 1', 'Amount') any idea how to add this values as a new column?

Answer (score 0):

If your Date column is not datetime then you can convert it and group by month like this:

```
df.groupby(df['Date'].to_datetime().dt.month).apply(weight_avg, 'Column 1', 'Amount')
```